# GET variable from url is ignored when after folder-like page

Tags: php, wordpress

At work (well more like an apprenticeship, dunno) I'm making a wordpress plugin that allows users to submit their posts (it's for a website catalog) with the ability to pay for some premium features. For this I'm using PayU.
I have a shortcode which I put on a page where users end up after the payment, and the shortcode shows appropiate message depending on GET variables. Eg. "your post awaits moderation" with a free post, "payment was successful" when it was so etc.

So when payment in PayU fails it will stick `&error=501` to the end of the url, so my code detects that and tells the user their payment failed and their post won't be submitted. And here's the thing.
When the confirmation page url is itself a variable, eg. ?post_id=71, everything works as expected. So for `mywebsite.com/?post_id=71&posttype=paid&error=501` the error is read and shortcode acts appropiately. But when the address in folder-like (sorry, really dunno how to call that) eg. `/confirmation`, `error` variable gets unnoticed. So with an address like `mywebsite.com/confirmation?posttype=paid&error=501` the result is a "payment successful" message. Order of variables doesn't seem to matter, `posttype` is always interpreted and `error` is always omitted.

I don't have access to the code right now but it's basically this:

```php
function my_shortcode() {
    if(!isset($_GET['posttype'])) {
        // some generic text to handle this unexpected condition
    }
    else if($_GET['posttype'] == 'free') {
        // nice message on how the post awaits moderation
    }
    else if($_GET['posttype'] == 'paid') {

        if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
            if($_GET['error'] == '501') {
                // payment was unsuccessful
            } else {
                // some generic text cause this isn't supposed to happen too
            }
        } else {
            // payment was successful
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I'd expect the error value to modify the behavior accordingly, instead it only does so when page address is itself a query.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it tomorrow

Comment: @GOKOP do a var_dump of $_GET. Logically irrespective of the url, request parameters should work. The only case when this shouldn't work is when your shortcode is not on that page which is unlikely but just to be sure, post your form code and shortcode, if they are different. If your form is generated via shortcode itself then the redirect page might be having issue.

Comment: var_dump shows just what you'd expect from the outcome.
`array(3) { ["page_id"]=> string(2) "71" ["posttype"]=> string(4) "paid" ["error"]=> string(3) "501" }` for the working case and `array(1) { ["posttype"]=> string(4) "paid" } ` when it's not working. To post the .htaccess I think I'll have to ask my boss for ftp access and he's not here yet.
My shortcode is only showing a string of text depending on the conditions, no forms involved. Unless you mean the form for submitting but I don't think it's relevant in any way.

Comment: Ok so apparently there are plugins for editing .htaccess so I don't need ftp. So the problem exists on three sites (that's how many I've tried) and htaccess of one of them is empty so it can't be the issue.

Comment: To make things even weirder, all variables are properly retreived when the variable is called something different than "error".

Comment: `error` is part of the query parameter names WP uses itself, https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars It is recommended that you don’t use any of the names on that list, otherwise you’ll easily run into trouble with the WP routing mechanism.

Comment: Well that's a problem then because this doesn't depend on me; it's PayU

Comment: Ok, I worked around this by making a separate php file which gets everything in $_GET, changes "error" to something else and then redirects to the wordpress page which has the shortcode, with modified data. Should I post an answer, edit my post or something?